# Global name canvas is not defined

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am just trying to print the layer name using python in my  QGIS plugin by following code.

```
allLayers = canvas.layers()
for i in allLayers: print i.name()
```

It is saying an error: Global name canvas is not defined. How to fix this?

Comment: could you include what software you're using?  It seems safe to say that the variable "canvas" has not been defined yet, but more information on your part would be helpful...

Comment: Yeah i am using QGIS. The post was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the wrong class. What you need to call is ***mapCanvas***, and not canvas.

Change your code to this:

```
allLayers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
for i in allLayers:
    print i.name()
```

This will print all of your current layers' names.

Also note that you need to indent the print line. I assume in your post this was just a copy/paste problem, but if not, go ahead and change it, or it will not work :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can i hardcore the layername alone like if layer name = this, do something in python?

Comment: You could put each layer into a seperate variable using that list. For example, if you want to refer to the first layer: layer1 = allLayers[0]

Comment: Or, for "true" hardcoding, something like this:

myLayer = QgsVectorLayer('D:/pyqgis/myshapefile.shp', 'the name that appears in the legend', 'ogr')